# What does `Unit = Unit` do and mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In the [ReKotlin repo](https://github.com/ReKotlin/ReKotlin) [README](https://github.com/ReKotlin/ReKotlin/blob/master/README.md), there is code that looks like this:

```
data class CounterActionIncrease(val unit: Unit = Unit): Action
```

What does the code `Unit = Unit` do and mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The assignment (i.e. `Unit = Unit`) in this context is how one defines a [default argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments). It's no different in concept than if you had:

```kotlin
class Foo(val bar: String = "Default Value")
```

Since [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/) is an [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) it's a singleton whose instance is referenced by the object's name. So `val unit: Unit = Unit` is assigning the instance of `Unit` as the default argument.

That said, it seems strange to have a class property with a type of `Unit`. The only reason I can think to do that is because [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) need to declare at least one parameter in the primary constructor, and for some reason the class has no need for "real" properties yet it must be a data class (though I don't understand the need for a data class in this case).

> To ensure consistency and meaningful behavior of the generated code, data classes have to fulfill the following requirements:
>
> - **The primary constructor needs to have at least one parameter;** *[emphasis added]*
> - All primary constructor parameters need to be marked as `val` or `var`;
> - Data classes cannot be abstract, open, sealed or inner;
> - (before 1.1) Data classes may only implement interfaces.

Comment: Lol but it is kinda funny, who will ever want to accept Unit as a parameter, its just a waste IMO to have a pointer to Unit as a property on object.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Agreed. The only reason to have it is to have an effectively no-property data class, which is weird in and of itself.

Comment: Ah got it, data classes without parameters aren't allowed :)

Comment: I asked one of the authors of ReKotlin and he said that your answer is correct.